# update a field value according to another in ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework

how can i change the value of a field according to another field value in entity framework mirations?

i have a Table named Tbl_Accounts with bellow columns:

1. ID (int)
2. Code (nvarchar(50))
3. Name (nvarchar(50))
4. ParentID  ( int : nullable )  -----> this is the ID of parent that is of type Account( a tree architecture)

In the old version of my program,the 'Code' column has a 3 length digit value,
for example i list some data stored in Tbl_Account in bellow:

- 1,'100','Parent1',null
- 2,'200','Parent2',null
- 3,'300','Parent3',null
- 4,'001','First Child OF Parent1',1
- 5,'002','Seccond Child OF Parent1',1
- 6,'001','First Child OF First Child Of Parent1',4
- 7,'001','First Child OF Seccond Child Of Parent1',5

Now:I want to change the value of codes like bellow according to the it's parent with migrations:

- 1, '100'         ,'Parent1',null
- 2, '200'         ,'Parent2',null
- 3, '300'         ,'Parent3',null
- 4, '100001'      ,'First Child OF Parent1',1
- 5,'100002'       ,'Seccond Child OF Parent1',1
- 6,'100001001'    ,'First Child OF First Child Of Parent1',4
- 7,'100002001'    ,'First Child OF Seccond Child Of Parent1',5

Note: code value of Record with ID=7:

- 100002  :the value of code column in record with ID=5
- 001  :the actual value of code column in record with ID=7

code value of Record with ID=5:

- 100  :the value of code column in record with ID=1
- 002  :the actual value of code column in record with ID=5

Comment: You wanna do this in a migration ? So you can perfectly use raw sql ,right ?

Comment: Migrations are about changing the schema of your database based on your entities, not the entries in the tables.

Comment: so please tell me what is the best way???,i want that any user runs the new version of my program for first time,the program updates values automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna do this in a migration, you can use raw sql.

The Sql (assuming you're working with Sql Server) would look like this (you need a recursive CTE, as an updated value can depend on a "previous" updated value)

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
    SELECT id, code
    FROM Tbl_Accounts
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.id, d.code + u.code
    FROM Tbl_Accounts AS u
    INNER JOIN cte AS d
        ON d.id = u.parent_id
)
update t
set t.code = c.code
from cte c
join Tbl_Accounts t on t.id = c.id
```

If you use Code first migrations, you can put this as a string variable, and just do (in th up method)

```
Sql(<yourStringVariableContainingTheSql);
```

You may also execute this query directly in your base(s), by the way.

See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59dcc/1) to be sure of the result

Comment: ok,thanks,but what about another databases??? all databases support Transact-SQL WITH common_table_expression??

Comment: @hosseinab no, of course. You're working with different dbs ?

Comment: Not yet but it is possible.

Comment: @hosseinab Well, so you may use other scripts for other db. I must admit that I never tried to use Code first migrations with different targetted dbs...